# Repeating Numbers in a two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to write a function, when given a two dimensional array. The first will be the value to repeat, the second will be the amount of times to repeat that value -- each sub-array will only have two values

The function should return a string with each of the given values repeated the appropriate number of times, each set of values should be separated by a comma. If there is only one set of values then the comma should be omitted.

For example:

```
console.log(repeatNumbers([[1, 10]]))                   // => 1111111111
console.log(repeatNumbers([[1, 2], [2, 3]]))            // => 11, 222
console.log(repeatNumbers([[10, 4], [34, 6], [92, 2]])) // => 10101010, 343434343434, 9292
```

How should I tackle this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You can just turn the number into a string and use [`string.repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat). To apply it to an array, you would use `map()` and then `join()` them. It's not 100% clear in the question whether that should be `join(',')` or `join(', ')`. The examples show a space after the comma, but the question just says separated by comma.

```js
function repeatNumbers(arr){
    return arr.map(([n, count]) => n.toString().repeat(count)).join(',')
}
console.log(repeatNumbers([[1, 10]])) 
console.log(repeatNumbers([[10, 4], [34, 6], [92, 2]]))
```

Comment: with the space `.join(', ')`

Answer (score 5):

`map` each sub-array to its character with `repeat` called on it, then join by commas:

```js
const repeatNumbers = arr => arr.map(
  ([char, repeats]) => String(char).repeat(repeats)
)
  .join(',');
console.log(repeatNumbers([[1, 10]])) // => 1111111111
console.log(repeatNumbers([[1, 2], [2, 3]])) // => 11, 222
console.log(repeatNumbers([[10, 4], [34, 6], [92, 2]])) // 10101010, 343434343434, 9292
```

Comment: Since two answers are the same i must say that this one appeared few seconds faster than the other one if that matters :D